# Frame disappear using pack_forget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a main window on which  when clicking the B1 button should remove  the frames using object.place_forget , object.pack_forget, so that i can create  a new window later on   .But I get error message .

File "./trial.py", line 60, in setup
    self.Data_frame.pack_forget()
AttributeError: Gui instance has no attribute 'Data_frame'

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import * 


class Gui(Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
                Frame.__init__(self,parent)
            # p_height=480
            #  p_width =720   
        self.parent=parent
            self.topframe=Frame(self.parent, bg = "black")
                self.topframe.config(highlightbackground='cyan',highlightthickness='2')
                self.topframe.pack()
            self.topframe.place(x=0,y=0,anchor=NW,height=480,width=720)
            self.Info_frame=Frame(self.parent, bg="#222")
        self.Info_frame.config(highlightbackground='black',highlightthickness='5')
            self.Info_frame.pack()
        self.Info_frame.place(x=5,y=5,height=50,width=710)
                label=Label(self.Info_frame,text="Main Screen",bg="#222",fg="cyan",font=("Helvetica",20)) 
                label.pack() 
             #   label.place(x=260,y=0) 

        self.Data_Frame=Frame(self.parent, bg = "cyan")
        self.Data_Frame.pack()
            self.Data_Frame.place(x=5,y=50,anchor=NW,height=390,width=525)
        self.Data_Frame.config(highlightbackground='black',highlightthickness='5')

                l1=Label(self.Data_Frame,text="L1",width=20,bg="cyan",anchor=NW,font=("Helvetica", 15))
        l1.place(x=13,y=10)     

            l2=Label(self.Data_Frame,text="L2",width=20,bg="cyan",anchor=NW,font=("Helvetica", 15))
        l2.place(x=13,y=40)     

        l3=Label(self.Data_Frame,text="L3",width=20,bg="cyan",anchor=NW,font=("Helvetica", 15))





            Nav_Frame=Frame(self.parent,bg="cyan")
        Nav_Frame.place(x=525,y=50,anchor=NW,height=390,width=190)
        Nav_Frame.config(highlightbackground='black',highlightthickness='5')

            b1=Button(Nav_Frame,text="B1",width=12,bd=2,fg="cyan",font=("Helvetica", 15),command=self.setup)
            b1.pack()
            b2=Button(Nav_Frame,text="B2",width=12,bd=2,fg="cyan",font=("Helvetica", 15),command=self.setup)
            b2.pack()
        b3=Button(Nav_Frame,text="B3",width=12,bd=2,fg="cyan",font=("Helvetica", 15),command=self.setup)
            b3.pack()



            Bot_Frame=Frame(self.parent,bg="#222")
        Bot_Frame.place(x=5,y=425,anchor=NW,height=50,width=710)
        Bot_Frame.config(highlightbackground='black',highlightthickness='5')

    def setup(self):

            self.Data_frame.pack_forget()
            self.Data_frame.place_forget()
        self.Info_frame.place_forget
        self.nfo_frame.pack_forget

if __name__== "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
        #root.config(cursor="none")
    app=Gui(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have been using `self.Data_Frame` and later `self.Data_frame`. Python names are case-sensitive.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

capital `F`,`Data_Frame` not `Data_frame`. You are also missing an `I` in `Info_Frame` and you were not calling the methods: :

```
    def setup(self):
        self.Data_Frame.pack_forget()
        self.Data_Frame.place_forget()
        self.Info_frame.place_forget() # call
        self.Info_frame.pack_forget() #  self.Info_frame not  self.nfo_frame
```

If you make those changes everything will work.